# Podchaser GraphQL Api, seem to be passing something incorrectly

Tags: javascript, api, graphql

I have the following gql query which is supposed to retrieve data from the podchaser api

```
const query = gql`
    query getGuests($identifier: PodcastIdentifier!) {
        podcast(
            identifier:$identifier
          ){
             credits{
                 data{
                    episodeCredits{
                        characters
                    }
                 }
             } 
          } 
        }  
    }
  `;
```

The docs are here for that request https://api-docs.podchaser.com/docs/reference/queries/podcast#arguments

I am running the request like so

```
const checkForGuests = (id) => {
    const variables = {
      identifier: {
        id: id,
        type: "SPOTIFY",
      },
    };

    const fetchPodcastsGuests = async () => {
      const data1 = await graphQLClient.request(query, variables);
      setData1(data1);
    };
    fetchPodcastsGuests();
  };
```

I am able to get ID's from a podcast with

```
 const search = gql`
    query {
      podcasts(searchTerm: "syntax") {
        data {
          id
          title
        }
      }
    }
  `;
```

The error I am getting is the following

```
Error: GraphQL Error (Code: 500): {"response":{"message":"Server Error","status":500,"headers":{"map":{"cache-control":"no-cache, private","content-type":"application/json"}}},"request":{"query":"\n    query getGuests($identifier: PodcastIdentifier!) {\n\t\tpodcast(\n\t\t\tidentifier:$identifier\n\t\t  ){\n\t\t\t credits{\n\t\t\t\t data{\n\t\t\t\t\tepisodeCredits{\n\t\t\t\t\t\tcharacters\n\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t }\n\t\t\t } \n\t\t  }\t\n\t\t}  \n    }\n  ","variables":{"identifier":{"id":"77080","type":"SPOTIFY"}}}}
```

Any help on this would be great, can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to do the query I need in the initial search, and noticed I was doing somethings wrong

```
const search = gql`
    query {
      podcasts(searchTerm: "zion 2.0") {
        data {
          id
          title
          credits{
            data{
              episodeCredits{
               data{
                 characters{
                   name
                 }
               }
             }
            }
          } 
        }
      }
    }
  `;
```